# Firebase data changing forever

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

im new to making app and trying to make a task list app using android studio, firebase, and kotlin. In MainActivity, i show the list of task that stored in fire base. then there is button to add a new task and store it into firebase. if i click on a task at MainActivity, the app will move to EditTaskActivity, which contain some EditText element, and if user fill that EditText, then press button "Save Change" in the EditTaskActivity, it supposed to store the data change in firebase. But the problem is, when i press the "Save Change" button, the data in firebase keep changing forever between the old data and new data, and make the app can't stopped working.

This is my MainActivity code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var titlePage: TextView
    private lateinit var subtitlePage: TextView
    private lateinit var endPage: TextView
    private lateinit var rvTasks: RecyclerView
    private var list: ArrayList<Task> = arrayListOf()
    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var btnAddNew: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        titlePage=findViewById(R.id.title_page)
        subtitlePage=findViewById(R.id.subtitle_page)
        endPage=findViewById(R.id.end_page)

        btnAddNew=findViewById(R.id.btn_addnew)

        rvTasks = findViewById(R.id.rv_taskList)
        rvTasks.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rvTasks.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("TaskListApp")
        reference.addValueEventListener( object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot){
                for(dataSnapshot1 in dataSnapshot.children){
                    var task: Task? = dataSnapshot1.getValue<Task>(Task::class.java)
                    if (task != null) {
                        list.add(task)
                    }
                }
                val taskAdapter = TaskAdapter(list,assets)
                rvTasks.adapter = taskAdapter
                taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } )

        btnAddNew.setOnClickListener { v ->
            if(v.id == R.id.btn_addnew){
                val moveToAddNew = Intent(this@MainActivity, AddNewTask::class.java)
                startActivity(moveToAddNew)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is My TaskAdapter code:

```kotlin
class TaskAdapter(private val taskList: ArrayList<Task>, assets: AssetManager): RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var someContext: Context

    inner class ListViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var taskTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_title)
        var taskDesc: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_desc)
        var taskDate: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_date)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_tasks, parent, false)
        someContext = parent.context
        return ListViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return taskList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val task = taskList[position]

        holder.taskTitle.text = task.taskTitle
        holder.taskDesc.text = task.taskDesc
        holder.taskDate.text = task.taskDate
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val moveToEdit = Intent(someContext, EditTask::class.java)
            moveToEdit.putExtra("tasktitle", task.taskTitle)
            moveToEdit.putExtra("taskdesc", task.taskDesc)
            moveToEdit.putExtra("taskdate", task.taskDate)
            moveToEdit.putExtra("taskkey", task.taskKey)
            someContext.startActivity(moveToEdit)
        }

    }
}
```

and this is my EditTaskActivity code:

```kotlin
class EditTask : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var pageTitle: TextView
    private lateinit var addNewTaskTitle: TextView
    private lateinit var inputTaskTitle: EditText
    private lateinit var addNewTaskDesc: TextView
    private lateinit var inputNewTaskDesc: EditText
    private lateinit var addNewTaskDueDate: TextView
    private lateinit var inputNewTaskDueDate: EditText

    private lateinit var btnSaveChange: Button
    private lateinit var btnDeleteTask: Button
    private lateinit var btnCancel: Button

    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var taskKey: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_task)
        taskKey = intent?.getStringExtra("taskkey").toString()
        pageTitle=findViewById(R.id.add_new_task_title_page)
        pageTitle.typeface=CircularBlack

        addNewTaskTitle=findViewById(R.id.new_task_title)
        addNewTaskTitle.typeface=CircularMedium

        inputTaskTitle=findViewById(R.id.add_task_title)
        inputTaskTitle.typeface=CircularBook
        inputTaskTitle.setText(intent.getStringExtra("tasktitle"))

        addNewTaskDesc=findViewById(R.id.new_task_desc)
        addNewTaskDesc.typeface=CircularMedium

        inputNewTaskDesc=findViewById(R.id.add_task_desc)
        inputNewTaskDesc.typeface=CircularBook
        inputNewTaskDesc.setText(intent.getStringExtra("taskdesc"))

        addNewTaskDueDate=findViewById(R.id.new_task_time)
        addNewTaskDueDate.typeface=CircularMedium

        inputNewTaskDueDate=findViewById(R.id.add_task_time)
        inputNewTaskDueDate.setText(intent.getStringExtra("taskdate"))

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("TaskListApp").child("Task$taskKey")

        btnSaveChange=findViewById(R.id.btn_save_change)
        btnSaveChange.setOnClickListener{ v ->
            if(v.id==R.id.btn_save_change) {
                reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        dataSnapshot.ref.child("taskTitle").setValue(inputTaskTitle.text.toString())
                        dataSnapshot.ref.child("taskDesc").setValue(inputNewTaskDesc.text.toString())
                        dataSnapshot.ref.child("taskDate").setValue(inputNewTaskDueDate.text.toString())
                        startActivity(Intent(this@EditTask, MainActivity::class.java))
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            "Action Cancelled, Error Occured",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                        startActivity(Intent(this@EditTask, MainActivity::class.java))
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        btnDeleteTask=findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_task)
        btnDeleteTask.setOnClickListener{v ->
            if(v.id==R.id.btn_delete_task){

                reference.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener {
                    if(it.isSuccessful){
                        startActivity(Intent(this@EditTask, MainActivity::class.java))
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed to delete task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        btnCancel=findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_edit)
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener{ v ->
            if(v.id == R.id.btn_cancel_edit) {
                startActivity(Intent(this@EditTask, MainActivity::class.java))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my AddNewTask activity code:

```kotlin
class AddNewTask : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var pageTitle: TextView
    private lateinit var addNewTaskTitle: TextView
    private lateinit var inputTaskTitle: EditText
    private lateinit var addNewTaskDesc: TextView
    private lateinit var inputNewTaskDesc: EditText
    private lateinit var addNewTaskDueDate: TextView
    private lateinit var inputNewTaskDueDate: EditText
    private lateinit var btnCreateTask: Button
    private lateinit var btnCancel: Button

    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference
    var taskNum: Int = Random.nextInt()

    private var taskKey: String = taskNum.toString()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_task)
        pageTitle=findViewById(R.id.add_new_task_title_page)
        pageTitle.typeface=CircularBlack

        addNewTaskTitle=findViewById(R.id.new_task_title)
        inputTaskTitle=findViewById(R.id.add_task_title)
        addNewTaskDesc=findViewById(R.id.new_task_desc)
        inputNewTaskDesc=findViewById(R.id.add_task_desc)
        addNewTaskDueDate=findViewById(R.id.new_task_time)
        inputNewTaskDueDate=findViewById(R.id.add_task_time)

        btnCreateTask=findViewById(R.id.btn_save_task)
        btnCreateTask.setOnClickListener(this)
        btnCancel=findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel)
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        when(v.id){
            R.id.btn_save_task -> {
                reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("TaskListApp").
                        child("Task$taskNum")
                reference.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
                    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        dataSnapshot.ref.child("taskTitle").setValue(inputTaskTitle.text.toString())
                        dataSnapshot.ref.child("taskDesc").setValue(inputNewTaskDesc.text.toString())
                        dataSnapshot.ref.child("taskDate").setValue(inputNewTaskDueDate.text.toString())
                        dataSnapshot.ref.child("taskKey").setValue(taskKey)
                        startActivity(Intent(this@AddNewTask, MainActivity::class.java))
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        startActivity(Intent(this@AddNewTask, MainActivity::class.java))
                    }
                })
            }
            R.id.btn_cancel -> {
                startActivity(Intent(this@AddNewTask, MainActivity::class.java))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **single value event listener** instead of **value event listener**

Use

```
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent
```

Instead of

```
reference.addValueEventListener
```

Because **value event listener** is **call all the time** when data changed into Firebase child but **single value event listener** is **only call one time**. So, maybe it was generated the issue for you.

Comment: @FauzanAbdillah Most welcome.If you are satisfied with my answer so can you give me answer as marked answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ChildEventListener` also with ValueEventListener.

Value listener will trigger method every time when data are changed in db and return all data

ChildEventListener also will will trigger method every time when data are changed in db but it's will returned item which is changes.

```
ChildEventListener listener= new ChildEventListener(){

    onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    // This method will be triggered in the event that this listener either failed at the server, or is removed as a result of the security and Firebase rules.
    }

    onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName){
     // triggered when a new child is added to the location to which this listener was added.

    //check and add new item to your adapter here
    }

    onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName){
     //  triggered when the data at a child location has changed.
    }

    onChildMoved(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
    // triggered when a child location's priority changes.
    }

    onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    // triggered when a child is removed from the location to which this listener was added.
    }
}
```

Then remove your value listener after read all items and add child listener to observe new items and changes

```
   reference.addValueEventListener( object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot){
            for(dataSnapshot1 in dataSnapshot.children){
                var task: Task? = dataSnapshot1.getValue<Task>(Task::class.java)
                if (task != null) {
                    list.add(task)
                }
            }
            val taskAdapter = TaskAdapter(list,assets)
            rvTasks.adapter = taskAdapter
            taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            reference.removeListener(this);
            reference.addValueEventListener(listener);
        }
```